# How to safely terminate a thread in Python

Tags: python-3.x, multithreading

I have below code, where I am using OpenCV to start webcam video. Along with that I also have a thread running that pings `www.google.com` to check network connectivity.

```
import time
import cv2
import os
from threading import Thread

stopThread = False

def CheckNetwork():
    global stopThread
    while True:
        time.sleep(60)
        host = "www.google.com"
        response = os.system("ping " + host)
        if response == 0:
            print("Internet host reachable")
        else:
            print("Internet host not reachable")
        if stopThread:
            break

def main():
    global stopThread
    Thread(target=CheckNetwork).start()
    cam = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
    while True:
        ret_val, img = cam.read()
        cv2.imshow('Camera', img)
        key = cv2.waitKey(1)
        if key == ord('q'):
            stopThread = True
            break
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()

main()
```

This code is running fine. If I have to close the application by pressing `q`, OpenCV window closes but application keeps running for 60sec because of the thread and only after 60sec whole application terminates safely.

I wanted to know if this is a good way to close the threads. Is there any better way available which can immediately terminate threads in Python?

Answer (score 0):

There's no native way of stopping a thread in Python. Instead of using a stop flag, you can also use `ctypes` that calls the Python API to raise an exception in the thread.

```py
import ctypes
# Other imports...

class ThreadWithException(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, name):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.name = name
             
    def run(self):
        # code here...
          
    def get_id(self):
        # returns id of the respective thread
        if hasattr(self, '_thread_id'):
            return self._thread_id
        for id, thread in threading._active.items():
            if thread is self:
                return id
  
    def raise_exception(self):
        thread_id = self.get_id()
        res = ctypes.pythonapi.PyThreadState_SetAsyncExc(thread_id,
              ctypes.py_object(SystemExit))
        if res > 1:
            ctypes.pythonapi.PyThreadState_SetAsyncExc(thread_id, 0)
            print('Exception raise failure')
```